# AWS EC2 VPC - How could one find the destination and data of high unexpected traffic from an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, tcpdump

For an EC2 instance (Linux) it was encountered huge unexpected network traffic, in and out. From 500 MB/5min to 6GB/5min for 6+ hours continuously. We do not have VPC flow logs enabled. It is suspected a security breach, an unwanted transferring of data.
We would be interested in knowing where and what data was transferred.
Questions:

1. Since this happened in the past and we did not have VPC flow logs enabled, is there a way for AWS to determine where the data was transferred (IP, hostname)?
2. In the case it happens in the future, I guess the solution is to have enabled AWS VPC Flowlogs on the EC2 instance interface https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html#flow-logs-default and check for dstaddr and pkt-dstaddr for outgoing traffic. May you confirm?
3. I guess to find what data (which files) was transmitted it is not possible for AWS to tell but which local (on EC2) solution would you advise? I am thinking to have a Cloudwatch monitor to alert us when throughput reaches a set threshold and then I can run a packet capture tool (tcpdump) to capture traffic on that interface (locally or on S3 - depending on the size).
4. Except AWS Flow Logs which implies additional costs, which local (on EC2, Linux)data traffic tool for monitoring would you recommend to run 24/7 and save logs?
   Thank you.

Comment: Consider signing up for [AWS Developer Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/plans/developers/), even if only temporarily.

Comment: We have enterprise support. Case is pending for an answer now. But wanted to get opinions from here also.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Shield is always running on all AWS accounts. If you have a Business or Enterprise support plan you could escalate to the AWS Shield Response Team (SRT) and they could assist you. [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)